# AKS adding new pool

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I am trying to add a new Node pool in my existing Kubernetes cluster. One of the required field is `kubernetes version`. No versions show up in the dropdown and thus I can not Add a new node pool. Any idea on why this is the issue ?[image]

Comment: looks like a bug.. try to run the command from the cli command - `az aks nodepool add \
    --resource-group myResourceGroup \
    --cluster-name myAKSCluster \
    --name mynodepool \
    --node-count 3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be a bug in the UI. As an alternative use the command [`az aks`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/aks-preview/aks/nodepool?view=azure-cli-latest)

```
az aks nodepool add --cluster-name --name --resource-group --kubernetes-version --node-count
```

To know Kubernetes version use `az aks get-versions` command

Answer (score 1):

This issue happens when the Kubernetes version of the AKS cluster has been retired. You can use the following command to list the supported versions in your region.

```
az aks get-versions -l southeastasia -o table
```

You then go to the **Cluster Configuration** of the AKS cluster and ensure the version is supported.

Once you upgrade the cluster to a supported version the drop down will start showing the values again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Best option is navigate to Cluster configuration.
2. update the  kubernates Version to latest.
3. Now come back again to node pools you will see the Kubernates version
   populating .
4. select that and add the node pool

[image: 1]

[image: 2]